# [SPARQL/DBPedia]can I catch the german wikipedia-URL from a result?

Tags: wikipedia, sparql, dbpedia

Can someone help me to catch the link for the German Wikipedia article?

For example, I have a query for all German films:

```
SELECT ?film
WHERE { ?film skos:subject http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:German_films }
```

Is there a option like `dbpedia:wikipage-de` that shows me the German site of Wikipedia?
All the results have only a prefix like foaf:page and the content called: [http]    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't

this information is not available in the english dbpedia (only german label and abstract)

you could use the label, it is usually the same as the article name.
The german dbpedia is another option, or you can download the german dumps (from dbpedia.org) and use them in you own server

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, but if you want to look up dbpedia-extracted content from the German Wikipedia, I think you need to look at http://de.dbpedia.org/; For instance, http://de.dbpedia.org/page/Sepsidae corresponds to the German Wikipedia page of http://dbpedia.org/page/Sepsidae on the English Wikipedia. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Your request doesn't work (for me at least). I had to do:

```
SELECT ?film
WHERE { ?film <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:German_films> }
```

I guess what you would like to do is something like:

```
SELECT ?film
WHERE { ?film <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Kategorie:Deutscher_Film> }
```

so you would get the articles from the German Wikipedia. Like @jimkont said, this request cannot be ran on the English dbpedia, you need to get the German dumps.